# SharePoint Graph API - There is no update page endpoint - looking for suggestions on best way to do this

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am currently working with The SharePoint Graph API.

This is the scenario I need to achieve:

- Somehow call page by name not ID
- If page called my_page_name.aspx exists

  - update it
- else

  - create the page

As far as I can work out, there is no update page end point in the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta

[image]

The only thing I can think of to do it the following:

- Call the page by name
- delete it
- create a new page with the same name with the new content I want to update

Any help on how I achieve what I need would be great

Comment: Hi RuSs, Yes, As of now we don't have any 'Update Page' endpoint feature and there is already a uservoice for this [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38969551-enable-updating-site-pages-via-graph-api). Please upvote this uservoice so that this feature could be developed in future. And also remember that since the pages endpoint is in beta these are subjected to change.

Comment: Moved this to Answer :)-

Comment: @Shiva  thanks for this and I will submit a user voice. Thing is I can’t mark this as the answer as you have only answered part of my question. I don’t need to use the beta api version so looking for help on how I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, As of now we don't have any 'Update Page' endpoint feature and there is already a uservoice for this here. Please upvote [this uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38969551-enable-updating-site-pages-via-graph-api) so that this feature could be developed in future. And also remember that since the pages endpoint is in beta these are subjected to change and its not recommended to use for production purpose.